# Pyinstaller does not look for the file inside the Python Virtual Environment

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pyinstaller

I want to convert Python code into standalone executable , the code uses numpy, scipy, and Pymc3 modules. I am using Python 3.6.4. I have created the project using Virtual Environment in Pycharm IDE. The command that I used to run pyinstaller is as follows:

```
venv/Scripts/pyinstaller --onefile src/POD.py
```

venv being the folder where virtual environment is stored and src being the folder where my Python source code ie. POD.py is saved. Pyinstaller runs just fine generates some warning message, but when I try to run the executable generated by pyinstaller it thrown as error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "POD.py", line 196, in <module>
  File "POD.py", line 79, in train
  File "Lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\var.py", line 155, in __mul__
  File "Lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 615, in __call__
  File "Lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\elemwise.py", line 482, in make_node
  File "Lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\elemwise.py", line 438, in      get_output_info
  File "Lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\elemwise.py", line 157, in __init__
  File "Lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 1308, in __init__
  File "Lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 1331, in load_c_code
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI126642\\theano\\tensor\\c_code\\dimshuffle.c'
[4756] Failed to execute script POD
```

Seems like it is trying to find the file dimshuffle.c outside of the virtual environment. In-fact the I can see that there is folder inside virtual environment which has the dim_shuffle.c code. I can find it inside virtual environment in following folder.

```
venv/Lib/site-packages/theano/tensor/c_code/dimshuffle,c
```

My question is how do I instruct pyinstaller to look for dimshuffle inside virtual environment folder?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem !! I have given-up on pyinstaller

Answer (score 1):

You can,

1. extend the sys.path by editing the spec file.

   ```
    pyi-makespec --paths=/path/to/thisdir \
            --paths=/path/to/otherdir myscript.py
   ```
2. List the hidden imports using the spec file.

for more info refer [this](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html)